# solve $1: ambiguous redirect

Tags: bash

I'm using this script to backup an old private instance of postgresql to gmail periodically:

```
#!/bin/bash
/opt/local/lib/postgresql83/bin/pg_dump maxgests -U postgres | gzip --best -c > $1 && (/opt/local/bin/mutt -s `date "+%d-%m-%Y-%H:%M"` -a $1 $2 < /dev/null)
```

As of late I'm getting this:

```
./postgres_to_gmail.sh: line 2: $1: ambiguous redirect
```

And the script no longer works. Mac OS X 10.6.8.

Can anytone tell what's wrong and how to fix it?

First argument is a path, like `/tmp/database.gz`

Second argument is the email.

Comment: Well what does $1 look like? Something else, you must quote **all** path-containing variables in your Bash scripts. Otherwise they’ll break when (not if, *when*) they contain spaces.

Comment: As an aside, I don't think the parentheses around the last command are necessary or useful.

Comment: You're right, I clarified the argument values.

Comment: Always use `#!/bin/bash -u` to get errors for unbound variables. Makes life much simpler

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`$1` is apparently empty.

As a general guidance, you should put your variable interpolations in double quotes, nearly always.

Comment: For detailed quoting guidance, see [When to wrap quotes around a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable).

Answer (score 1):

the caller doesn't set the arguments ($1 $2)
you should check the crontab or the program which calls is periodically
more

```
$ echo > $1
bash: $1: ambiguous redirect
```